# Conversational IPA

Tags: ipa, online-resources

Is there any online dictionary which shows conversational version of phrases e.g. /ə ˈkʌpə tiː/ instead of /ˈə ˈkʌp ˈəv ˈtiː/ ? And if there's no one, where can I obtain conversation versions of phrases?

Comment: Do you need this for a specific dialect of English? Because dictionaries mirror standard or common usage, and different people will speak slightly differently in conversation. http://accent.gmu.edu/ shows how people from all over the world pronounce one specific set of phrases. Alternately, what's the focus of your study?

Comment: Furthermore there is an enormous variation even in a single person's usage depending on the level of formality, speech pace, environment conditions, etc. What you are more likely to find is the standard pronunciation on one side and some ruleset specifying how it tends to be shifted in common speech under the various circumstances mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to be a British speaker and I need a dictionary to see conversational pronunciation of texts, i.e. without letters which are away in speech.